# Small Spoiler. Can I store 2 cars in a specific Safehouse Garage?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

In Fraklin's new Safehouse can you safe 2 cars? Also where do cars go if they disappear from there? And they aren't in the Impound is it a glitch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can really only store one car there safely. Otherwise they tend to glitch very badly. If the car disappears from your garage, its gone for good, and it disappeared because of a glitch.

Cars only go to the impound if you've abandoned them outside. The impound doesn't clean up glitches.